# Changing Amazon Textract bounding box values

Tags: python, amazon-s3, bounding-box, amazon-textract

I'm writing a code in python for text extraction in python using Textract. My aim is to extract data from a restaurant menu card as item and price and I'm using tabular form to get data extracted. But during some image extraction some tables are not there in result.
To solve this i tried changing the BoundingBox attribute and still not working.

```
response = textractmodule.analyze_document(
Document={
    'S3Object': {
        'Bucket': s3BucketName,
        'Name': TabledocumentName
    }
},
FeatureTypes=["TABLES"])
doc = Document(response)
print ('------------- Print Table detected text ------------------------------')
for page in doc.pages:
    for table in page.tables:
        for r, row in enumerate(table.rows):
            itemName  = ""
            for c, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
                print("Table[{}][{}] = {}".format(r, c, cell.text))
```

This is the code and I'm not getting to change its bounding box. Or is there any other issue or any other method??